# Can't upload app to Fabric/Crashlytics

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have the latest Fabric mac app (2.0.1) on my laptop, with Crashlytics framework version 3.3.4, and XCode 6.4.

After generating the archive file with Xcode, I tried to upload the build to Fabric. However, after selecting the testers and editing the release note, the uploading failed, with no error, no any response.

I am just wondering if the version of fabric/crashlytics or Xcode that mismatch? Or is there something wrong with the latest fabric mac.app?

Comment: Same problem with Fabric (2.0.1) and Xcode 7.

Comment: There’s _everything_ wrong with the Fabric Mac app.